# Interface to communicate to web pages from android application

Tags: java, android, expert-system

I am trying to implement a "Doctor Finder" application for android which will have a symptom checker facility like webMD. Since webMD don't have any API's I must create my own expert system (which takes a lot of time) or need to find something similar to webMD which offers public API. I found [NIL API](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/api/) from National Library of Medicine US and I doubt it would be useful in my scenario.

Now the actual question, Is it possible to use webMD's online symptoms checker using an interface from android. I don't want to show the HTML page within my app but to send and receive information through it? If not is there any APIs available to serve this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using "selenium".
Its a tool used for automated testing of web applications. you can navigate and enter information in the web page and get results using this.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: https://github.com/selendroid/demoproject-selendroid/blob/master/src/main/java/io/selendroid/demo/mobileweb/MobileWebTest.java